# Как в процедуре вставить в таблицу только заданные столбцы?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, процедуры, stored-procedures

Из  столбца `petit.username` и из столбца `block.regname` по условиям вставляются данные в столбцы `ACCEPTANCE_LINE, LINE_REVIEW, REGNAME_LINE, USERNAME_LINE` в таблицу `petit`.

Но в таблице `petit` много столбцов.

Как сделать, чтобы не указывать все эти столбцы? Например, `c.f5, c.f6, […]`, не нужны.

```
create or replace procedure LINE2 is
    a1 integer;
begin
    for c in ( 
        select 
            case when t2.regname like '%sp3%' then '5-555'  end ACCEPTANCE_LINE,
            case when t.username like '%sp3%' then '5-444'  end LINE_REVIEW,
            case when t2.regname='53'         then '12345'  end REGNAME_LINE,
            case when t.username='53'         then '123456' end USERNAME_LINE ,
            t2.regname F5,t.username F6,
            […]
        from petit t, block t2 where t.id=t2.id_ger and trunc(t2.date_end) > '01.01.2000'
        ) loop
            select HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL into a1 from petit t where rownum=1;
            insert  into petit values(
                c.ACCEPTANCE_LINE, c.LINE_REVIEW,c.REGNAME_LINE, c.USERNAME_LINE, 
                c.f5, c.f6, […]
                );
            commit;
        end loop;        
    commit;
end LINE2;
```

Comment: `insert into petit (col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, val3)`

Comment: Вам нужно быстрое решение или правильное? Если последнее, то отформатируйте код.

Comment: Скорее правильное, чтобы в будущем при добавлении полей не править процедуру

Comment: Ну правильно будет, никогда не делать вставку в цикле, а вставлять из запроса - `insert into tab (col1, clo2, col3) select ... from tab1, tab2 ... where ...`.

Comment: Сравнивать, к примеру данные вначале были занесены в таблицы ACCEPTANCE_LINE, LINE_REVIEW, REGNAME_LINE и USERNAME_LINE и чтобы их повторно не заносить в туже таблицу. В таблице есть свой id. Нужно чтобы было сравнение id и ACCEPTANCE_LINE, LINE_REVIEW, REGNAME_LINE и USERNAME_LINE

Comment: Пока не вижу проблем, сравнивать прямо в запросе.

Comment: Если вы приведёте веские аргументы, что в запросе это сделать сложно, то есть ещё N-цать способов решить не пребегая к циклу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но в таблице petit много полей, как сделать чтобы не прописывать все эти поля ...

Указать, какие нужны:

```
insert into petit (col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, val3);
```

---

Никогда не делайте вставку в цикле, всегда вставлятйте массово из запроса. В данном случае, процедура будет выглядеть так:

```
create or replace procedure LINE2 is
begin
    insert into petit (id, acceptance_line, line_review, regname_line, username_line) 
        select 
            HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL id,
            case when t2.regname like '%sp3%' then '5-555'  end ACCEPTANCE_LINE,
            case when t.username like '%sp3%' then '5-444'  end LINE_REVIEW,
            case when t2.regname='53'         then '12345'  end REGNAME_LINE,
            case when t.username='53'         then '123456' end USERNAME_LINE
        from petit t, block t2 
        where t.id=t2.id_ger and trunc (t2.date_end) > date'2000-01-01';
    -- trace (sql%rowcount||' row(s) inserted into petit.'); --по необходимости
end LINE2;
```

Фиксировть изменения в процедуре не следует. Код, который вызывает процедуру должен решать, что делать с транзакцией - фиксировать ее или откатывать. Как минимум так:

```
LINE2;
commit;
```

Comment: @wq55 Всё правильно. Если колонка объявлена NOT NULL , то вы должны её во вставке указать, и спрва и слева от values.

Comment: @wq55 Пока написал комментарий, вы свой удалили. То есть, с ошибкой вы разобрались?

Comment: С колонками я разобрался что-то типа такого        
            TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') DATE_INPUT,
            TO_CHAR(substr(t.Type_Id,1,2)) TYPE_ID
Но когда эта процедура срабатывает то создаются новые столбцы, немного не правильно задал вопрос, мне похоже нужно UPDATE а не INSERT

Comment: @wq55 Скорее вам нужен upsert, др.сл. merge. Поишите на эти ключевые слова, уже были такие вопросы. Не получится, задайте новый вопрос. Текуший вопрос можете отметить как принятый, он правильный для задачи как описано в вопросе.

Comment: @wq55 Поэтому так важно перед тем, как задать вопрос, создать  [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Если бы вы не не заметили своей ошибки при его создании, заметил бы я при ответе. Многие думают - сэкономлю время, и бах копи-паста простынки кода из продуктивной среды. Но это иллюзия экономии, начинается несравнимо большая трата времени, и своего, и чужого.

Comment: Спасибо!  Задам новый вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать представление для вставки, которое включает только столбцы обязательные для вставки. Столбцы обьявленные как `NOT NULL` - всегда обязательны.

Предположим есть такая таблица и надо при вставке обязательнo заполнить `col1`:

```
create table tab (
    id int generated always as identity, 
    col1 varchar2 (8) not null, 
    col2 varchar2 (8) default 'undef', 
    created date default sysdate, 
    modified varchar2 (8) default 'itwasme')
/
create or replace view vtab as
    select col1 from tab
/
```

Тогда всё очень просто -- через курсор заполнить необходимые столбцы, а при вставке вообще никаких столбцов указывать не нужно:

```
declare
    type vtabcur is ref cursor return vtab%rowtype; 
    rc vtabcur; 
    type vtabrows is table of vtab%rowtype;
    newrows vtabrows; 
begin 
    open rc for
        select trim (column_value) col1
        from xmlTable ('"aaa","bbb","ccc"');
    fetch rc bulk collect into newrows;
    /** 
    здесь при необходимости можно изменить/дополнить новые записи согласно бизнес логике  
    */
    forall rix in 1..newrows.count
        insert into vtab values newrows(rix);
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
        ID COL1     COL2     CREATED    MODIFIED
---------- -------- -------- ---------- --------
         1 aaa      undef    2020-08-22 itwasme 
         2 bbb      undef    2020-08-22 itwasme 
         3 ccc      undef    2020-08-22 itwasme
```

---

PS Принятый ТС ответ является решением в его конкретном случае. Данное решение предпочтительно для похожих задач, так как оно более гибкое, и вместе с тем, не менее производительное.